How to execute member method in FamilyAsyncNotifier of riverpod?
How to execute member method in FamilyAsyncNotifier?
(This is kind of continuous question to my previous question.)
I initialized my FamilyAsyncNotifier by passing parameter to it. However, now I am not able to execute member method in FamilyAsyncNotifier.
when it was just AsyncNotifier, member method was called like this.

await ref.read(postViewModel.notifier).fetchTargetPost(targetPostId);

However, I am not able to call it with FamilyAsyncNotifier. Does anybody know how to call member method in FamilyAsyncNotifier? I just wanted to pass parameter to AsyncNotifier but it seems like it is getting more complicated with FamilyAsyncNotifier. I really appreciate anybody's help on it.
final postViewModel =
    AsyncNotifierProvider.family<PostViewModel, Post?, String>(
  () => PostViewModel(),
);

class PostViewModel extends FamilyAsyncNotifier<Post?, String> implements BasePostListInterface {

  late final FetchPostUseCase _fetchPostUseCase =
      ref.read(fetchPostUseCaseProvider);

  @override
  FutureOr<Post?> build(String targetPostDocumentId) async { // <- now I am able to initialize it with parameter
    return _fetchPostUseCase(targetPostDocumentId);
  }

  Future<Post> fetchTargetPost(String targetPostDocumentId) async { // However, I can't execute this member method from UI.
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    Post post = Post.empty();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard( () async {
      post = await _fetchPostUseCase(targetPostDocumentId);
      return post;
    });
    return post;
  }
}


postViewModel.notifier should be postViewModel(familykey).notifier. That is, since you have a family of providers, you must identify which provider you want the notifier for.

What is familykey in this context? Could you please provide example code or any other details?

Whatever you gave it when you instantiated the family member.  Oh, you have a broken constructor.  Replace your constructor with PostViewModel.new, and then it will accept a family key in ref.watch and ref.listen.

Also, your notifier is missing the build() method.  Are you not getting lints on that?
